# Two tables side by side in a container won't float

Tags: html, css

I have a problem while trying to place two tables next to each other in a div which is supposed to be scrollable horizontally (x-axis).

When placed outside the container div, the tables float perfectly next to each other, but when inside the container, a break occurs after the first table.

```css
.scroll-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: chocolate;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

table {
    display: table;
    float: left;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<p>without the scroll-container:</p>
<table>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td><td>Dummy</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not giving a `width` to your `table`,

Plus I change you `table` properties from:

```
table {
 display:table;
 float:left;
}
```

to

```
table {
 display:table-cell;
 width:50% /* only if you need to be equal tables */
}
```

check snippet bellow:

```css
.scroll-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: chocolate;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;

}
table {
  display: table-cell;
  width:50% /* only if you need to be equal tables */
  
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
      <td>Dummy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the scroll-container at a fixed with, with the two tables side by side inside the scroll-container which then should be scrollable along the x-axis.

Comment: Works! Thanks. But is there any way to have the tables width be set to auto? The tables that are going to be used in production will vary with its data. One could be 80% and the other 20%, and at another time 20% and 80%.

Comment: I updated my answer, but yes, you can do one of 2 things: either set on `table` `width:auto` or simply remove `width`